# Get the latest actual value without passing it in useEffect array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I have my component

```
interface SearchResultsProps {
  refinement: string;
  searchTerms: string;
  currentPage: number;
}

const SearchResults: FunctionComponent<SearchResultsProps> = ({
  refinement,
  searchTerms,
  currentPage,
}) => {
  const { formatMessage } = useIntl();
  const { analyticsService } = useContainerProps();
  const shouldRender = searchTerms.length > 0;
  const { data, isFetching, isLoading } = usePagedQuery({
    refinement,
    terms: searchTerms,
    count: recordsPerPage,
    offset: (currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage,
    queryEnabled: shouldRender,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerms) {
      analyticsService?.logEvent(ANALYTICS_EVENTS.SEARCH_COMPLETED, {
        total_results: data?.hits.total.value,
        error_message: null,
      });
    }
  }, [searchTerms]);
...
```

I need to call this log function inside useEffect hook only when the searchTerms string is changed. The problem is that `total_result` is equal to the previous state of value. So I need somehow get the actual latest value of `data?.hits.total.value`. Is it possible to do it without making useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerms) {
      analyticsService?.logEvent(ANALYTICS_EVENTS.SEARCH_COMPLETED, {
        total_results: data?.hits.total.value,
        error_message: null,
      });
    }
  }, [searchTerms, data?.hits.total.value]);
```

Because in some cases the `total_results` can be the same, so it will not call my logEvent function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useRef to refer to the latest values

```
const { data, isFetching, isLoading } = usePagedQuery({
    refinement,
    terms: searchTerms,
    count: recordsPerPage,
    offset: (currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage,
    queryEnabled: shouldRender,
  });

  const hitsRef = useRef();
  // refer to value from the latest render cycle, or may in onSuccess, onLoad function
  hitsRef.current = data?.hits.total.value;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerms) {
      analyticsService?.logEvent(ANALYTICS_EVENTS.SEARCH_COMPLETED, {
        total_results: hitsRef.current,  // use the ref here
        error_message: null,
      });
    }
  }, [searchTerms]);
```

The problem you are facing is described in the [new beta docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/separating-events-from-effects#reading-latest-props-and-state-with-effect-events) `useEffectEvent` seems to be in RFC, so we are left with [useRef](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/referencing-values-with-refs)

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm getting the same previous result, it didn't helped

Comment: If I put timeout in useEffect it would work

Comment: Instead of search Terms may be you  can put data as dependency

Comment: Also tried this, but not helped when the searchTerms is different and data keeps the same

Comment: Why not use `isLoading`, `isSuccess` or some other flag which indicates successful data fetch and then refer the latest `searchTerm` and hits value

Comment: `useQuery`  can be passed `onSuccess` event handler, from which you can log the event, if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

As described above your problem can be solved with useEffectEvent (when it fires) or with ref, of course it's a wonder why it didn't help you because useEffect fires within 200-250ms after the render phase starts so your ref should already be with the right value, but not less, I would like to propose a polyfill that would do about the useEffectEvent principle, it is not perfect but it can help in situations like yours:

```
const useEffectEvent = (callback) => {
  const ref = useRef(callback);

  ref.current = callback;

  return (...args) => {
    ref.current(...args);
  }
}
```

And then you could use it as follows.

```
const { data, isFetching, isLoading } = usePagedQuery({
    refinement,
    terms: searchTerms,
    count: recordsPerPage,
    offset: (currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage,
    queryEnabled: shouldRender,
  });

  const onAnalitics = useEffectEvent(() => {
     analyticsService?.logEvent(ANALYTICS_EVENTS.SEARCH_COMPLETED, {
        total_results: data?.hits.total.value,
        error_message: null,
      });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerms) {
      onAnalitics()
    }
    
    // We don't need to add the function in the dependency
    // because it closes the ref which in turn will update
    // the function on each rendering file
  }, [searchTerms]);
```