# Is this an accurate polyfill of react's useEffectEvent?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is this an accurate polyfill of react's upcoming `useEffectEvent` hook? Does it present any potential issues?

One part I was not sure about was whether the ref is guaranteed to have been updated prior to the returned function being used in any other effects. I think I'm okay on this front so long as I never use the rather esoteric `useInsertionEffect` anywhere else in my code, but I would like to confirm that.

```js
function useEffectEvent(callback) {
  const fnRef = useRef(null)
  useInsertionEffect(() => {
    fnRef.current = callback
  }) 
  return (...args) => {
    return fnRef.current.apply(null, args)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't think the React team has proposed an official polyfill for `useEffectEvent` (at least I haven't seen it).

Having said that, you can see a polyfill inside the [RFC for the now defunct `useEvent`](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md#internal-implementation) which initially used `useLayoutEffect`. And in an early version of [Separating Events from Effects](https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects), Dan Abramov showed an updated version that looked like this (no longer visible in the docs):

```
import { useRef, useInsertionEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

// The useEvent API has not yet been added to React,
// so this is a temporary shim to make this sandbox work.
// You're not expected to write code like this yourself.

export function useEvent(fn) {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useInsertionEffect(() => {
    ref.current = fn;
  }, [fn]);
  return useCallback((...args) => {
    const f = ref.current;
    return f(...args);
  }, []);
}
```

This polyfill uses `useInsertionEffect`. I believe that the reason for this choice is that [insertion effects are the first to run](https://codesandbox.io/s/effects-nr33el?from-embed) (compared with `useLayoutEffect` and `useEffect`). So it is pretty safe to assume that the ref is updated before any of your other effects run.

Later on, the RFC for `useEvent` [was shelved](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/220#issuecomment-1259938816) and `useEffectEvent` started to [show in the docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/experimental_useEffectEvent). Nonetheless, the same polyfill can be reused to implement `useEffectEvent` since the exposed behaviour is the same.

Please note that with this polyfill, the hook returns a stable function (thanks to `useCallback(..., [])`), which might not be necessary but is more fool proof (in case the consumer adds the returned function to the dependencies of the effect by mistake).

If you want to understand more about the polyfill, I've blogged about it in: [A look inside the useEvent polyfill from the new React docs](https://blog.bitsrc.io/a-look-inside-the-useevent-polyfill-from-the-new-react-docs-d1c4739e8072).

Answer (score 3):

Reading the [current documentation](https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects), you can compare your approach with another [polyfill that uses the useEffectEvent principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75747740/6309): it is quite similar to the original polyfill you provided, with the only difference being the immediate assignment of the callback function to the `ref`:

```js
const useEffectEvent = (callback) => {
  const ref = useRef(callback);

  ref.current = callback;

  return (...args) => {
    ref.current(...args);
  }
}
```

This [polyfill](https://blog.logrocket.com/use-polyfills-react-app/#what-is-polyfill) attempts to mimic the functionality of `useEffectEvent` by storing a reference to the callback function and returning a function that invokes the latest version of the callback.

Concerning your question about whether the `ref` is guaranteed to have been updated prior to the returned function being used in any other effects, the `ref` should be updated by the time it is used in other effects because refs are updated during the render phase before effects run.
In both polyfills, the `ref` is updated before the returned function is invoked, ensuring that the most recent version of the callback is used.

However, there are some caveats to consider in both cases:

- Both solutions do not provide the exact semantics of `useEffectEvent`. They do not automatically "break the chain" between reactivity of effects and code that should not be reactive.
- They do not prevent the callback from capturing values from the render where the hook was called. This means that if the callback uses any props or state, it could potentially use stale values if those props or state change between when the hook is called and when the callback is invoked.
- The use of `useInsertionEffect` in your polyfill is not recommended unless you are working on a CSS-in-JS library and need a place to inject the styles. According to the [React documentation](https://ja.react.dev/reference/react/useInsertionEffect), `useInsertionEffect` fires before any DOM mutations and is primarily designed for injecting styles before any DOM updates occur.

So, these polyfills are not perfect and do not fully mimic the behavior of the upcoming `useEffectEvent` hook.

---

To elaborate:

Again, from "[**Separating Events from Effects**](https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects)", I believe [`useEffectEvent`](https://react.dev/reference/react/experimental_useEffectEvent) is designed to separate non-reactive logic from the reactive logic that's inherent in `useEffect`. This means that the logic inside an Effect Event is non-reactive and always "sees" the latest values of your props and state, regardless of when it is invoked. This is the fundamental behavior that these polyfills are trying to mimic.

But those polyfills might diverge from the official `useEffectEvent` because:

1. **Timing of Callback Execution:** In React, the timing of effect execution is carefully managed. Effects are run after the render phase, ensuring that they always have the latest state and props. However, the polyfills use a `ref` to store the callback and then return a function that invokes the latest version of the callback. This could potentially introduce timing issues where the callback is invoked before the `ref` has been updated with the latest callback.
2. **Reactivity and Dependency Tracking:** In the polyfills, the user of the hook has the responsibility to ensure that any props or state used in the callback are managed correctly. The official `useEffectEvent` is designed to handle this automatically. See also [`facebook/react` PR 25881](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/25881#issuecomment-1564843395)

> This means that if the callback uses any props or state, it could potentially use stale values if those props or state change between when the hook is called and when the callback is invoked.

3. **Integration with React's Internal Mechanisms:** The official `useEffectEvent` will be integrated with React's internal mechanisms for managing effects and updates. It is designed to work seamlessly with the rest of React's features, providing a consistent and predictable behavior. The polyfills, on the other hand, are implemented in userland and may not interact with React's internal mechanisms in the same way. This could potentially lead to unexpected behavior or edge cases that are not present with the official hook.
4. **Compatibility with Future React Features:** As React continues to evolve, new features and changes could potentially impact how effects and callbacks work. The official `useEffectEvent` will be maintained and updated along with the rest of React to ensure compatibility with future changes. The polyfills, however, may not be compatible with future changes to React, and could require updates or modifications to continue working as expected.

These polyfills can be useful for accessing the latest values in a callback invoked from an effect, they might not, however, fully replicate the functionality and semantics of the `useEffectEvent`.

---

On the point 2:

> "This means that if the callback uses any props or state, it could potentially use stale values if those props or state change between when the hook is called and when the callback is invoked."

In React, function components render in response to changes in props and state. During this render, the component function is called and all the code inside the function is executed with the current values of props and state.

When a callback function is created inside a component, it captures the current values of props and state in its closure. This is known as "closing over" the props or state. If the callback is invoked later, it will use the values of props and state from when it was created, not the current values.

This is usually fine for event handlers (like `onClick`), because they run in response to user actions, not in response to React re-renders. However, for callbacks that are passed to `useEffect` or a similar hook, this can cause problems. These callbacks are typically intended to respond to changes in props or state, so if they use stale values, they might not behave correctly.

For instance:

```js
function MyComponent({ prop }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(prop);
  }, []);
}
```

In this component, the `useEffect` callback will log the initial value of `prop`, but it won't log any changes to `prop`. This is because the callback closes over the initial value of `prop` and doesn't "see" subsequent changes.

To fix this, you could add `prop` to the dependency array of `useEffect`:

```js
function MyComponent({ prop }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(prop);
  }, [prop]);
}
```

Now, the callback will be recreated (and thus close over the new value of `prop`) whenever `prop` changes.

With `useEffectEvent`, the callback is supposed to always "see" the latest values of props and state, without needing to be recreated. This is different from `useEffect`, and it's one of the main reasons to use `useEffectEvent`.

In the polyfills you posted, the user of the hook (i.e., the developer writing the component) has to manually ensure that the callback uses the correct values of props and state. This could involve using `useRef` to store the latest values, or recreating the callback more frequently, or some other strategy.

In the worst case, if the developer doesn't manage the props or state correctly, the callback could use stale values, leading to incorrect behavior. This is the risk when using the polyfills instead of the real `useEffectEvent` (when it becomes available).

---

> I believe the version of the polyfill where the `ref` is updated directly within the render (rather than within an effect) is not safe in concurrent react (since it means the render is no longer "pure").
> This is why I used `useInsertionEffect` in my version.

True: In Concurrent Mode, React may choose to start rendering a given component, then pause this rendering process to start working on something else more urgent, before finally coming back to finish what it started.

Updating a `ref` directly in the render phase, as one of the polyfills does, could potentially lead to inconsistencies in a Concurrent Mode scenario, because if React starts rendering a component but then pauses and restarts the rendering (due to a higher priority update), the `ref` would be updated twice - once for the initial, interrupted render and again for the restarted render. This could lead to unpredictable behavior, as the `ref` value may not correspond to the state and props at the time the effect runs.

On the other hand, your version of the polyfill uses [`useInsertionEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useInsertionEffect) to update the `ref`. The `useInsertionEffect` hook is meant to execute *before* any DOM mutations occur, but *after* the render phase is complete. This ensures that by the time the effect runs, the render phase is not going to be interrupted or restarted, and the `ref` will have the correct value.

However, it is important to note that `useInsertionEffect` is primarily intended for CSS-in-JS libraries to insert styles before any DOM mutations occur. Its usage for other purposes might not be recommended, and might have its own edge cases or issues. For instance, by the time `useInsertionEffect` runs, refs are not attached yet, and the DOM is not yet updated.

So yes, `useInsertionEffect` can be a solution to avoid direct ref updates during the render phase in Concurrent Mode.
But it is not without its caveats, and it is not the intended use case for this hook.

Comment: I don't understand your first two bullet points - could you expand more on how exactly the behaviour of these polyfils could diverge from the official hook?

Side note - I believe the version of the polyfil where the ref is updated directly within the render (rather than within an effect) is not safe in concurrent react (since it means the render is no longer "pure"). This is why I used useInsertionEffect in my version.

Comment: As Dan Abramov said, [there is no great way to polyfill this](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/220#issuecomment-1118027152). `useInsertionEffect` seems a better tradeoff to me as 1/ it runs earlier than the other effects, 2/ it's rarely used so it's unlikely that someone would try to read your ref in another `useInsertionEffect`, 3/ it keeps the render function pure and avoid issues with concurrency

Comment: @GyumFox Good points. I agree, and I have upvoted your anwer.